# How to encrypt the stanzas sent to ejabberd

Tags: ejabberd, public-key-encryption

I am currently using ejabberd. My app is working fine but I have a question. How can I encrypt the stanzas sent to ejabberd from the client (Presence, Message, IQ). I am currently using TLS transport protocol for client to server communication and server to server communications. What I want to do is encrypt the data sent to ejabberd from the clients to server using a public key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are talking about End-To-End encryption

If we are talking about XMPP in general, the following things are available and can be used:

- [Off-the-Record Messaging (OTR)](https://otr.cypherpunks.ca/) and [XEP-0364](https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0364.html)
- [OpenPGP: XEP-0027](https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0027.html) and [XEP-0374](https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0374.html)
- [Signal Protocol](https://signal.org/docs/)
- [OMEMO](https://conversations.im/omemo/) and [XEP-omemo](https://conversations.im/omemo/xep-omemo.html)

Regarding Ejabberd - as stated here https://www.process-one.net/en/ejabberd/protocols/ - they support **OpenPGP** out of the box.

Other things (at least OTR) also can be used in any messaging apps.

Anyway, it's a very broad topic and you need to invest some good amount of time to implement End-To-End encryption, it's not a quick task

Comment: thanks alot for the help. just a quick question. Aren't OTR and OMEMO is implemented only on the client side or does my XMPP server (ejabberd) has to support it too